# If $f(n) = O(g(n)) \Rightarrow \log(f(n)) = O(\log(g(n))$ But not $2^{f(n)} = O(2^{g(n)})$, why?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, asymptotics

I know that:

$$
f(n) = O(g(n))
$$

Namely:

$$
\exists c > 0, \exists N \in N, \forall n > N: f(n) \leq c \cdot g(n)
$$

Now i know that from this we can conclude that:

$$
\lg f(n) = O(\lg g(n))
$$

But we cant conclude:

$$
2^{f(n)} = O(2^{g(n)})
$$

Because there is a counter example: $f(n) = 2n, g(n) = n$

But i dont understand the logic, why it is working with $log$ but not with $2^x$?

Comment: Simply by using the definition of $O$. Indeed $log$ will keep the definition : $lg(f) < ln(c) +ln(g) $ (when $ln(g)$ goes to infty $ln(c) $ can be avoided and putting $ln(c) <kln(g) $. Yet with $2^f<2^(cg)$ and because the power of 2 isn't separable into two product or sum.